# Extracting data continuously from RDS MySQL schemas in parallel

Tags: python, sql, multithreading, amazon-web-services, apache-spark

I have got a requirement to extract data from Amazon Aurora RDS instance and load it to S3 to make it a data lake for analytics purposes. There are multiple schemas/databases in one instance and each schema has a similar set of tables. I need to pull selective columns from these tables for all schemas in parallel. This should happen in real-time capturing the DML operations periodically.

There may arise the question of using dedicated services like Data Migration or Copy activity provided by AWS. But I can't use them since the plan is to make the solution cloud platform independent as it could be hosted on Azure down the line.

I was thinking Apache Spark could be used for this, but I got to know it doesn't support JDBC as a source in Structured streaming. I read about multi-threading and multiprocessing techniques in Python for this but have to assess if they are suitable (the idea is to run the code as daemon threads, each thread fetching data from the tables of a single schema in the background and they run continuously in defined cycles, say every 5 minutes). The data synchronization between RDS tables and S3 is also a crucial aspect to consider.

To talk more about the data in the source tables, they have an auto-increment ID field but are not sequential and might be missing a few numbers in between as a result of the removal of those rows due to the inactivity of the corresponding entity, say customers. It is not needed to pull the entire data of a record, only a few are pulled which would be been predefined in the configuration. The solution must be reliable, sustainable, and automatable.

Now, I'm quite confused to decide which approach to use and how to implement the solution once decided. Hence, I seek the help of people who dealt with or know of any solution to this problem statement. I'm happy to provide more info in case it is required to get to the right solution. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This question is probably too broad and opinion-based for this site, though I hope someone can provide some useful input.  Regardless, you're probably better off posting questions like this in an AWS forum.

Comment: Thanks, @JeffLearman for your suggestion. I have posted the question on the AWS forum. However, I am hoping people here would share their opinion based on their experience with these services.

Comment: _"make the solution cloud platform independent"_ > that's wishful thinking. Each cloud has its own solutions for Ops (IAM, monitoring backup, failover etc). The best you can do is provide a **migration path** between clouds, based on what each cloud offers at the time of writing.

Comment: In that particular case, you should consider a third-party CDC solutiion such as Attunity. Check whether it supports all major clouds, and check also the surprising resemblance with Amazon DMS _(after all, did you think AWS could produce a mature CDC solution out of nowhere...?)_

Comment: _"Delta lake by Databricks ...  can't use since ... it could be hosted on Azure"_ > Duh. Databricks runs on Azure. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/delta/ You mean you did not even check that??

Comment: Hi @SamsonScharfrichter. I read about Delta lake and this is what I found: Delta Lake runs on top of your existing data lake (reference: https://databricks.com/blog/2019/09/03/transform-your-aws-data-lake-using-databricks-delta-and-aws-glue-data-catalog-service.html). So, it is required to have the data lake on S3 before using Delta lake. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Also, feel free to comment on leveraging python's daemon threads concept for this use case if you have an idea about it or any other suitable approach that you have in your mind. Thanks